# Why does React not hold focus on an input when you return a const vs a function from the component?

Tags: reactjs

There is some odd behavior that I haven't noticed before happening in one of my react components. I have a component where I've wrapped an `input` for more functionality. The gist of the code looks something like this:

```
function MyInput(props) {
  const Input = <input {...props} />
  return <Label>{Input}</Label>
}
```

However, I thought it might be nice to assign a function to the const so I could use JSX function invocation syntax so that it would be slightly more readable:

```
function MyInput(props) {
  const Input = () => <input {...props} />
  return (
    <Label>
      <Input />
    </Label>
  )
}
```

However, now the input loses focus on each re-render, and I have to click into the input to enter more characters (it is an uncontrolled component, but a debounced event handler causes a re-render when the user stops typing). Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new Input component every time the MyInput runs, so React removes the previous input that was in the DOM and replaces it with the new one.

For a similar reason, the following creates instances from two separate classes, rather than two instances from the same class:

```js
const makeInstance = () => {
  class Class {}
  return new Class();
};
const i1 = makeInstance();
const i2 = makeInstance();
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(i1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(i2)
);
```

For your issue, move your Input declaration outside the component body so that it's seen as the same component every time the parent runs.

```
const Input = () => <input {...props} />
function MyInput(props) {
  // ...
```

There's nothing wrong with creating component functions dynamically, just be careful not to recreate them on every render.